# Is there a way to be notified when the user makes changes in a wxStyledTextCtrl?

Tags: events, wxwidgets, wxstyledtextctrl

I have a wxWidgets application that has a wxStyledTextCtrl. But for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get notified of modification events.

I have the following code:

```
void CMainWindow::OnDocumentModified(wxStyledTextEvent & event)
{
    wxString msg;
    msg << event.GetModificationType();
    wxMessageBox(msg);
}
```

This gets called for `EVT_STC_MODIFIED`.

When I run the application and press a key, the message box displays `1040` and `8209`. When I call `SetText` the same two messages are displayed.

How can I differentiate between user events and programmatically-generated events?

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.yellowbrain.com/stc/stc_event.html#modtype for possible values.

Comment: I know what the values are - they just don't seem to match what the event handler gets.